# Is attaching oneself to Nationalism of a non Islamic country a big sin?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, non-muslim-countries

I came across these hadiths which perplexed me:

> It is narrated that, Rasulullah (sal Allahu alaihi wa sallam) said:
>
> “He is Not one of us who calls for asabiyyah, (tribalism/nationalism)
> or who fights for asabiyyah, or who dies for asabiyyah.”
> [Abu Dawud]
>
> You are all the children of Adam and Adam was made of clay. People should give up their pride in nations because that is a coal from the coals of Hell-fire. If they do not give this up Allah (swt) will consider them lower than the lowly worm which pushes itself through Khara (dung)." [Abu Dawud and Tirmidhi]
>
> The Prophet sallallaahu ‘alayhi wa sallam said:“Whosoever leaves off obedience and separates from the Jamaa’ah and dies, he dies a death of jaahiliyyah. Whoever fights under the banner of the blind, becoming angry for ‘asabiyyah (partisanship and party spirit), or calling to ‘asabiyyah, or assisting ‘asabiyyah, then dies, he dies a death of jaahiliyyah." [Sahih Muslim (6/21)]

It seems to me that Islam abhors racism, ethnicism, tribalism, and its newer version, nationalism. Differences of language, color, cuisine and accent were meant to identify humanity, not to be used to ridicule or fight each other like proclaiming ourselves to be Syed,Khan,Qureshi,Pakistani, Indian, Iranian, American etc.
So does it mean Islam forbids Nationalism and patriotism towards ones own non Islamic country or race?

Comment: not sure what you are asking... the answer is already part of your question: Nationalism has no place in Islam... whether it has to be qualified as "haram" or "makrooh" or whatever is more of a question for some scholar (which is not really what ISE is about IMO)....

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/what-is-the-view-of-islam-on-nationalism-and-patriotism) helps a bit in clarification...

Answer (score 0):

Allah has put desires in humans and also given them intelligence. It's our duty to not let our desires get hold of us and fog our judgement.

It is a natural tendency to have affection for the place you are born in, where you spend your childhood. Noone can deny these. Islam does not stop these natural desires, but only asks you to put it under limits. The limitation is that it should not override your love for Allah and the Prophet Muhammad PBUH. You don't have to go in some other country to encouter these desires as mentioned [here](http://quran.com/9/24)

Answer (score 0):

The place of birth  tribes nationality where the problems over which the message of Allah and Rasool brought about change. Allah identified us as an Ummah and Rasool as brothers in the Deen. The last Surman of the Prophet states clearly this concept. But Nationalism divides the Ummah by man made boundaries. It makes wars between Nations where a muslim is made to kill a muslim . This is against Allah's Law. hence Haram . Allah knows best