# National Anthem in Islamic Schools

Tags: quran, hadith, fatwa

Can you please provide us with some guidelines regarding the national anthem being sung by our school during its various functions?

Is it permissible, standing up for it, placing hands on chest etc..?

Comment: related : http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/is-attaching-oneself-to-nationalism-of-a-non-islamic-country-a-big-sin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A national anthem is a hymn or song of praise and love for one's nation. And all praise is for Allah Alone. So I don't think it is appropriate for a Muslim to sing the national anthem. Allow me to explain.

Praising someone or something per se is not haraam. ("My wife is a great cook," or "My country is beautiful.") But making a ritual out of it for anything or anyone other than Allah (I feel) makes it shirk. "Ritual praise" is praise that is done either at particular times or particular occasions. For example, each time we stand in Salaah and say in Arabic that "All Praise is for Allah..." we are doing ritual praise. And ritual praise I feel is `solely` Allah's prerogative.

Love for one's country is not unnatural or even haraam; however restricting it to singing a particular song or anthem to show one's love may not be correct. Love for one's nation implies that one works to alleviate the problems and sufferings of her people. Standing once a year during the national day and saluting the national flag and singing the national anthem in a loud and emotionally-charged voice reeks of hypocrisy. Do something practical for your nation, I feel you will be doing her a greater service.

This is my opinion only and I am no scholar.

Comment: National anthem is a symbol of our love for our country. The importance of symbolism can not be undermined as this is the way humans remember things. This is the same thing as Namaz, although the main thing is God consciousness. but a "symbol" is made "farz", which indicate the importance of it.

Comment: related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/is-attaching-oneself-to-nationalism-of-a-non-islamic-country-a-big-sin

Answer (score 1):

National anthem is a symbol of our affection to our homeland, just like namaz(prayer) shows our affection to Allah.

Since their is a natural tendency of humans for things like our place of birth, where we spend our childhood and our country, Islam does not have anything against it. So it perfectly fine to sing it with all its components (like placing hands on the chest)

What is objectionable that our love for Allah and his Prophet (PBUH) exceeds our love of other things and thus we undermine His commandments.

Comment: i am proud of my country and i love it the most.

Answer (score 1):

The love of country is a human virtue and the anthem at schools is one way of showing it all together which is what it is about. I don't see what would be wrong with it unless it is intended to replace a religious ritual. It would be like avoiding physical exercise in consideration of namaz.

Regarding Najeeb's answer -- "ritual praise I feel is solely Allah's prerogative"-- by all means, all **religious** ritual praise is solely for Allah. But national anthem is not a religious praise.

Not a scholar-- my personal thought.

Not a member here-- can write answers but no comments.